# How to prove that there is only one way to express a composite number as a product of primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I hope the title is self-explanatory.

Source:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJ3CD9M3nEQ

time stamp 2:04

Comment: I will always suggest checking the proof of uniqueness of prime factorization (part of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).

Comment: Or, just to hint it out, think: if a number has two different prime factorizations (here, take it to be the lowest number of its kind), couldn't you use Euclid's lemma to cancel out the prime factors in both the forms once you equate them? e.g. , I have a number $n$ of tqo different prime factorizations $\prod\limits_{i=1}^m p_i^{a_i}$  and $\prod\limits_{j=1}^n q_i^{b_i}$ ($p$,$q$ are primes). If I equate them both, can't I cancel each prime factor WLOG?

Comment: Cancel here means dividing off from both sides...

Answer (score -1):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number such that $n = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$ = $q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}...q_{n}^{\beta_{n}}$ with $\{p_{1},...,p_{k},q_{1},...,q_{n}\}$ be distinct primes. What can you say about the divisor $q_{1}...q_{n}$?

Comment: @MikeDesgorttes, speaking from my experience, I tell you not to answer simple questions like these as doing so should fetch you downvotes. I am already suffering for having done so.

Comment: @Spectre noted, i will wait next time.

Comment: @Spectre The issue is not that the question is "simple" but rather that it is a dupe of a FAQ, with hundreds of prior good answers that already say all that can be said.  Adding further (dupe) answers is [strongly discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242) (unless they contain significant novelty - in which case they should be added to the dupe target).

Comment: But more likely the dv is due to the fact that the above is far from a proof of existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque yeah, I saw that later. Actually, it was mistake that I didn't check for dupes.

Comment: @MikeDesgrottes oh, don't worry. It already had an answer so it had to be closed.